# Deployed version not showing correct responsive design

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a web app made with React.
Basically the navbar is causing issues. I am using conditional rendering to trigger responsiveness in the navbar. It is working fine on the local host but the deployed version is triggering the mobile navbar for pcs and vice versa.
Here is how it looks on the local host. The mobile version:

[local mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXMhj.png)
The pc version:
[local pc version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Cea.png)
Which is how it is supposed to work.

This is the deployed version. The mobile version:
[deployed mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qosGT.png)
And the pc version:
[deployed pc version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwXN0.png)

This is the code for header:

```
function Header({scrolling}) {

  var [isBurger, setIsBurger] = useState(false);
  var [isNav, setIsNav] = useState(false);
  var [isSearchBar, setIsSearchBar] = useState(false);
  var [isScreenSize, setIsScreenSize] = useState(0);

  

  const { width } = useWindowSize();

  //Nav button-----------------------------------
  var handleClickOnBurger = () => {
    setIsBurger((prevIsBurger) => !prevIsBurger);
    setIsNav((prevIsNav) => !prevIsNav);
  }


  //-----------------------------------------------
  //Search bar ------------------------
  var handleClickOnSearch = () => {
    setIsSearchBar((prevIsSearchbar) => !prevIsSearchbar)
  }
  //-----------------------------------
  function checkWidth() {
    if (isScreenSize >= 768) {
      setIsSearchBar(false);
      setIsBurger(false);
      setIsNav(true);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsScreenSize(width);
    checkWidth();
  });
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-md-4 px-md-5 my-3 shadow-sm headerBody">
      <Navbar callFunc={handleClickOnBurger} btnHook={isBurger} navHook={isNav}
      scroller={scrolling}
      />
      {!isSearchBar && <Logo />}
      <Searchbar callFunc={handleClickOnSearch} btnHook={isSearchBar} />
    </div>
  );
}

function useWindowSize() {
  // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      // Set window width/height to state
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }

    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();

    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount


  return windowSize;
}

export default Header;
```

This is the navbar:

```
import NavigationLinks from "./NavigationLinks";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react";



function Navbar(props) {

    var icon;
    var burgerIcon = "iconamoon:menu-burger-horizontal-bold";
    var xIcon = "tabler:x";

    const navBarLinks = [
        {
            text: "home",
            path: "/#heroHome"
        },
        {
            text: "about",
            path: "/#about"
        },
        {
            text: "for partners",
            path: "/#partners"
        }
    ]
    const styleMid = "visibilityHiddenMid";
    const styleSmall = "visibilityHiddenSmall navbarSmall";
    var styleFinal;
    


    return (
        <>
            <span className="visually-hidden">
                {styleFinal = props.btnHook ? styleSmall : styleMid}
                {icon = props.btnHook ? xIcon : burgerIcon}
            </span>
            <button className="bg bg-transparent ms-2 border border-0 visibilityHiddenSmall"
                onClick={props.callFunc}
            >
                <Icon icon={icon}
                    className="color text-black fs-1 fw-lighter bg-transparent" />
            </button>
            <div className={"col-12 col-md-4 " + styleFinal}>


                <div
                    className="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-start justify-content-md-left mx-3 my-4 my-md-0 align-items-strat align-items-md-center">
                    {navBarLinks.map((link, index) => {
                        return (<NavigationLinks text={link.text} path={link.path} key={index} />)

                    })}

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Search bar is somewhat similar to this code as well. If I can correct navbar, then I can correct the search bar as well.

At first I thought this was due to me not passing keys. However, even after providing keys it was not fixed.

From what I can tell, the state hooks are not properly being set in the deployed version. I do not have any idea why it is doing that when it is working on local version.

Answer (score 0):

The navbar responsiveness issue you're having in the released version but not in the local version may be caused by behavioral variations between your local environment and the deployed environment. The method by which the screen size is initially set using the `useEffect` hook may be a case in point.

Make sure to include width as a dependency in your `useEffect` hook within the `useWindowSize` custom hook so that the effect is re-executed each time the width varies.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleResize() {
    setWindowSize({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  handleResize();

  return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
}, [width]);
```

If this doesn't work than the best solution is using `CSS`. If you want your navbar to adjust its layout according to screen size, think about using CSS media queries rather than JavaScript alone. This may result in behavior that is more consistent across various settings and devices.

Comment: I tried this solution but it did not work. I tried putting it in the component function but it threw errors.
I want to use React and hooks to better grasp the idea of React. CSS is an option but I want it to be the last resort.
What I don't understand is, why is it working on local server but not on the deployed one.

Comment: Look, useEffect work as a side code when a component render, You can have that in mind, but I will suggest you go with css you can toggle queries using css + js both